# dynamic grouping by month in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, case, advantage-database-server

I am using CASE statements to group data into Month columns, like this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  1 THEN ROUND(value) END) as jan,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  2 THEN ROUND(value) END) as feb,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  3 THEN ROUND(value) END) as mar
```

Is it possible to NOT have to define the different CASE groupings?

I want to define the data range in the WHERE statement, and then have the report group by month, for whatever range I define. For example, maybe my report starts with July'20, and not Jan.

Is this possible in an SQL query?

Thanks

edit - example output:

```
+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+
|       | July  | Aug  |  Sep  |  etc  |
+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+
| value | 435 € | 24 € | 234 € | 453 € |
+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+
```

edit - possible solution/workaround:

if I do the following, it can be considered "semi-dynamic". I still need to define the month "buckets", but they can be trigged by the starting date (the month({ d '2021-01-01' }) part can also later be replaced with a variable, so that is also fixed in the code.

```
SUM (CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  month({ d '2021-01-01' }) THEN value END) as month_1,
SUM (CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  month({ d '2021-01-01' })+1 THEN value END) as month_2,
SUM (CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  month({ d '2021-01-01' })+2 THEN value END) as month_3,
etc
```

the main downside is that I have to hard-code the number of month groupings. So i'd be happy to hear of a better solution!

Comment: Requesting different number of columns means you want dynamic SQL. Check the feature in your DBMS docs.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Hi, sorry - I have updated with the ADS tag and with example output

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dynamic sql statement to generate the result into a temporary table and then return the result from the temporary table. Here is an example:

```
declare sqlStr string;
sqlStr = 'SELECT 1 AS column1, 2 AS column2 INTO #temp FROM system.iota';

execute immediate sqlStr;

select * from #temp;
```

The logic to generate the required grouping is up to you. You will need to use [the while loop to construct the statement text.](https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage12/index.html?master_while.htm)